# How to add class on next div in angular 6 like accordion?

Tags: html, css, angular

Below is the code of CSS, ts and HTML files. i want create a custom accordion and i am in new in angular so want to create that when i click on div then class should add on same div and next to it. Currently i am doing with adding class on same and next div and adding display none/block. Please help..
 Below is HTML file:

```
 <div class="accordion">
  <div
    class="accordion-header"
    (click)="clickEvent()"
    [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : ''"
  >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        Calculation of the error -1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
        <span class="accordion-icon">
          <fa-icon [icon]="icon.minus" class="minusIcon"></fa-icon>
          <fa-icon [icon]="icon.plus" class="plusIcon"></fa-icon>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secOption" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''">
    details
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is ts file:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  faMinus,
  faPlus,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
@Component({
  selector: "app-accordion",
  templateUrl: "./accordion.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./accordion.component.scss"]
})
export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit {
  status: boolean = false;
  clickEvent() {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }

  icon = {

    minus: faMinus,
    plus: faPlus,
  };
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''" for [class.active]="status"